# Currency conversion with current Exchange rates

Tags: multi-currency, currency, conversion

I need to convert the Currency from EURO to USD , I am using the fields are

1. TestCurrency__c - Currency
2. CurrencyConvert - Formulafield(Currency datatype)

My Organization Corporate Currency is "EURO".

Here i enter the **TestCurrency** data as Euro then the **CurrencyConvert** field should be changed as USD with current exchange rates. Is this possible to implement in formula field? How the Conversion will happens using formula fields or triggers ?

Answer (score 4):

I once wrote a utility method within a `Util.cls`  that would convert an amount in currency X to the org currency using the appropriate DatedCOnversionRate. This would be invoked by a trigger on the object in question containing the currency amount that needs the org currency value. The trigger would use this method and save the result in a separate custom field like `Amount_USD__c` if USD was the org currency.

Adapt as needed for your use case

```
// Singleton, remember when first referenced, key = DatedConversionRate.id
private static Map<ID,DatedConversionRate>              dcrIdToDcrMap;                      

//  ----------------------------------------
//  convertToOrgCurrency - convert value in some ISO currency to org currency as of given date
//  ----------------------------------------
public static Decimal convertToOrgCurrency(String currencyIso, Decimal currencyVal, Date currencyDate) {
    Decimal res;
    if (currencyIso == null || currencyVal == null) {}
    else {
        if (dcrIdToDcrMap == null)              // build the map only once for life of the transaoction
            dcrIdToDcrMap = new Map<ID,DatedConversionRate> ([select id, isoCode, conversionrate, nextStartDate, startDate from DatedConversionRate]);
        for (DatedConversionRate dcr: dcrIdToDcrMap.values()) {
            if (dcr.isoCode != currencyIso)                                         continue;   // look for a match in table against input currency
            if (currencyDate < dcr.startDate || currencyDate >= dcr.nextStartDate)  continue;   // not in the range of effective dates
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'Converting using dcr: ' + dcr);
            res =  currencyVal / dcr.conversionRate;
            break;  
        }
    }
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'convertToOrgCurrency res= ' + res);
    return res;
}

//  ----------------------------------------
//  convertFromOrgCurrency - convert value in org currency to some iso currency as of given date 
//  ----------------------------------------
public static Decimal convertFromOrgCurrency(String currencyIso, Decimal currencyVal, Date currencyDate) {
    Decimal res;
    if (currencyIso == null || currencyVal == null) {}
    else {
        if (dcrIdToDcrMap == null)              // build the map only once for life of the transaoction
            dcrIdToDcrMap = new Map<ID,DatedConversionRate> ([select id, isoCode, conversionrate, nextStartDate, startDate from DatedConversionRate]);
        for (DatedConversionRate dcr: dcrIdToDcrMap.values()) {
            if (dcr.isoCode != currencyIso)                                         continue;   // look for a match in table against input currency
            if (currencyDate < dcr.startDate || currencyDate >= dcr.nextStartDate)  continue;   // not in the range of effective dates
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'Converting using dcr: ' + dcr);
            res =  currencyVal * dcr.conversionRate;
            break;  
        }
    }
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'convertFromOrgCurrency res= ' + res);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment @crop1645, here my organisation currency is "EURO".  I need to convert the EURO to USD with current exchange rates.

Comment: added the reverse case; Martin is correct that formulas can't use dated exchange rates

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know **you can't do that** using a formula field.

In Salesforce you assign the `CurrencyISOCode` (this field is visible when [you enabled Multi-currency in your Org](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_enable_multicurrency.htm&language=en_US)) and the `amount` (any currency field). 
Then Salesforce will show you the converted amount depending of the user's default currency,  in reports and layouts.

[image]
[image]

I don't think that you can force any conversion by formula but maybe you can achieve that using some Apex by querying `CurrencyType`.

More info about currencies in [SFDC official doc](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_currency.htm&language=en_US)