# Display Converted Currency on Visualforce page inDeveloper Edition

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce

i have a price(currency data type) and currency(pick list data type i.e(INR,USD,GBP))  custom fields  in account object.when ever i enter a value in price(INR 70) field it should display the corresponding value as INR 70(USD 1) in price field in visualforce page.how to write controller for my requirement Any help on this issue is highly appreciated

Apex page :

```
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
          <apex:pageBlockButtons >
              <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>
  </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Is INR70 record currency and USD1 User Currency?

Comment: if we enter 70 in indian currency it should display  INR and corresponding USD in price firld

Comment: what is the org currency? INR or USD ? See also - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/57659/2602