# Is there a way to query a currency field in a specific currency?

Tags: soql, multi-currency, currency

I have to do a VF with a "total" field for Quotes in a multi-currency org.

Is there a way for me to obtain the `QuoteLineItem.UnitPrice` in U$D regardless of the user's currency configuration?

Comment: I think you'd have to get the dated exchange rate and do the conversion manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using `Advanced Currency Management`, the [dated exchange rates don't apply to objects other than those related to Opportunities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=administration_about_advanced_currency_management.htm&type=5)

> Dated exchange rates are used for opportunities, opportunity products, opportunity product schedules, campaign opportunity fields, opportunity splits, and reports related to these objects and fields. Dated exchange rates are not used in forecasting, currency fields in other objects, or currency fields in other types of reports.

In this use case, what I've done in the past is define a shadow `Number` field on the `Quote` and `QuoteLineItem` called `Amount_USD__c` and compute it manually using a beforeInsert/update trigger by fetching values from the `DatedConversionRate` object. See [this answer for an example implementation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57615/currency-conversion-with-current-exchange-rates/57659#57659). You need to decide what "date" to use as the filter

- Is it the quote's Opportunity's CloseDate?
- Is it today's date?
- Is it some date on the Quote object?

You want the shadow field to be a `Number`, not a `Currency`

If using a non-advanced currency management implementation where currency rates are fixed (essentially, they are the current exchange rates), then ...

- If the running user always will have local currency = USD

Then you can do SOQL

```
SELECT ... ConvertCurrency(UnitPrice), ... FROM QuoteLineItem
```