# How can we use Dated Exchange Rates values in formula fields?

Tags: formula, formula-field, currency, convertcurrency, currencyisocode

I have a formula(Checkbox) field on the Opportunity object, which shows TRUE, when Some_Value__c (formula(Currency)) field >= 6000$:

```
Some_Value__c / CURRENCYRATE(TEXT(CurrencyIsoCode)) >= 6000
```

Default currency in our org is USD, but we have records with other currencies. We also have enabled **Advanced Currency Management is enabled**. Salesforce use those currencies, which could be updated manually in *Currencies* (Setup -> Company Profile -> Manage Currencies). But in the Opportunity records in UI, currency rate values are always get from *Dated Exchange Rates* ((Setup -> Company Profile -> Manage Dated Exchange Rates)).

So we have different values because of different rate values. As I know, there is no ability inSalesforce to use Dated Exchange Rates values in Formula fields.

So the question is do we have  any ability to use Dated Exchange Rates values to have actual values in Opportunity records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you are correct that formula fields can not take advantage of dated exchange rates

An Opportunity will [always use Dated Exchange Rates](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=administration_about_advanced_currency_management.htm) on all Currency fields with `CloseDate` being the lookup key across the configured Dated Exchange Rates.

If you wanted an Opportunity field to use a different exchange rate than would be specified by the `CloseDate`, you need to make that field a `Number` and set it via a trigger or Lightning Flow.  It would never display OOTB with a currency symbol though unless you overrode that part of the page with VF or LWC

An example of how to do this can be found in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/57659/2602)

Comment: but how can I do it via trigger? Because I didn't find Dated Exchange Rates as an Opportunity field.

Comment: @DmitriyYurkin - edited my answer

Comment: Cool! Looks like a plan! Thank you very much!