# How to use Corporate Currency Value in Approvals instead of Quote's Currency?

Tags: multi-currency, approval-process, convertcurrency

Multi currency is enabled in my Org.
I am using Approvals for Quote Object.
If Net Amount is less than 10,000 it requires Manager Approval.
If Net Amount is greater than 10,000 it requires Finance Team Approval.

When currency value is EUR and Net Amount is EUR 10,000 (USD 12,048.19), it required Finance Team Approval as it is greater than 10,000 USD. But in my case its taking EUR 10,000 and Manager Approval is triggering.

How can we achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One approach

- Use a separate field, trigger-managed, on Quote `Amount_USD__c` that has the amount in USD. This [answer shows how you can do this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/57659/2602)
- Then, your approval process always references the value in `Amount_USD__c`